Get the Value of HTML Element Using JSDom
Seems like this should be really fundamental action, yet I can't find any documentation or examples on how to do this.  If I have some HTML, and I want to retrieve a particular value and set it as a variable, how do I do that?
Context:
Working with an old MVC single layer app that only returns HTML responses.
Example:


const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

const kmsiResponse = await post(
      {
        ctx: loginCtx,
        hpgRequestId: loginSessionId,
        flowToken: loginSft,
        canary: loginCanary,
      },
      { url: 'myUrl' }
    );

    const kmsiResponseText = await kmsiResponse.text();
    const kmsiDom = new JSDOM(kmsiResponseText);
    console.log('JSDOM', kmsiDom.window.document.getElementsByName('id_token'));
<form method="POST" name="hiddenform" action="https://someUrl/">
   <input type="hidden" name="id_token" value="xxxxxxxxxx">
</form>



Output:
JSDOM NodeList {}

Typo: getElemenByName should be getElementsByName. It returns  a list of nodes. You need to index it or loop over it, then use .value to get the value.

kmsiDom.window.document.getElementsByName('id_token')[0].value

It's a bit strange that a POST request would return HTML. The general setup here smells a bit funny. You might want to provide more context of what you're trying to do here and preferably a [mcve].

While the earlier comments are not wrong, using getElementsByTagName() is not really appropriate because it not only returns a "live" node list, but because you are only interested in getting a reference to a single node, you should use kmsiDom.window.document.querySelector("[name='id_token']");. Learn more about .querySelector() here.

@ggorlen good point, added a context section.

Based on @Scott Marcus comment, this works:
console.log('JSDOM', kmsiDom.window.document.querySelector("[name = 'id_token']").value);

Console output - JSDOM xxxxxxx
I do need to also retrieve a list of values for another request, so will also be referencing the comments related to iteration, thanks all!
